# How to fix case when child items breaks parent boundary?

Tags: css, animation

The problem is that sidebar menu list items breaks parent boundary. How can i fix this, kind of not let childs go beyond parent width?
Working on sliding out from left side navigation site menu. 
It looks fine as is, the actual problem happens when i hover over list items.
As you can see list items reveals themself immideately, going beyond parent boundary. This looks awful. I pretty sure the issue can be fixed with css, but unfortunately my knoweledge is not solid at this moment. Could you please help me out with the solution to the issue? Thanks in advance!

This image shows what the correct behaviour should be.
[image]

```css
body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    
    img {
      position: relative;
      color: #999;
    }
    
    #one {
      padding: 17px 15px 15px 17px;
    }
    
    #two {
      padding: 20px 14px 15px 12px;
    }
    
    #three {
      padding: 15px 17px 15px 15px;
    }
    
    #four {
      padding: 20px 16px 15px 17px;
    }
    
    #five {
      padding: 20px 14px 15px 17px;
    }
    
    #six {
      padding: 17px 14px 15px 14px;
    }
    
    nav {
      background: #1b1e22;
      border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 60px;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: width .5s linear;
    }
    
    nav > ul {
      margin: 7px 0;
    }
    
    nav li {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 250px;
      transition: width .5s linear;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #24272a;
    }
    
    nav li > a {
      height: 60px;
      color: #999;
      font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;
      display: table;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      padding: 15px 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 5s linear;
      transition: all 5s linear;
    }
    
    nav span {
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 190px;
    }
    
    a:hover,
    a:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    nav {
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    nav ul,
    nav li {
      outline: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      color: #104E8B;
      background-color: #343536;
    }
    
    .main-menu:hover,
    nav.main-menu.expanded {
      width: 250px;
      overflow: visible;
    }
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img id="one" src="https://i.imgur.com/RcWtM2a.png" alt="" />
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Строительные проекты
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="two" src="https://i.imgur.com/wKDZKMl.png" alt="" />
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Строительные товары
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="three" src="https://i.imgur.com/oztvKJ0.png" alt="" />
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Строительные работы
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <img id="four" src="https://i.imgur.com/MT1dCFF.png" alt="" />
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Недвижемость
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img id="five" src="https://i.imgur.com/uICbjKw.png" alt="" />
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Мебель
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img id="six" src="https://i.imgur.com/nHnYpBg.png" alt="" />
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Строител. калькулятор
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>


    </ul>


  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: What part of it isn't working correctly, seems to be working in both of your examples.

Comment: The only bug I see is that the items appear instantly when hovered, rather than being masked by their container as it slides out. That is easily fixed by changing `overflow: visible` to `overflow: hidden` for `.main-menu`. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbGagV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to consider `width` for the transition and must keep `overflow` hidden as it is for following class:

```
.main-menu:hover,
nav.main-menu.expanded {
    width: 250px;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}
```

Here is the updated codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqbEqj